# Inspect HttpRequestMessage just before it is sent

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, httpclient

I have been tasked with integrating with the [Amazon Gift Codes On Demand (AGCOD)](https://s3.amazonaws.com/AGCOD/tech_spec/AGCODTechSpec.pdf) RESTful API. We are required to sign our requests using [Signature Version 4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html), something that is performed by their [AWS SDK for .NET](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/) for other services, but not AGCOD.

I am using the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) class from the [System.Net.Http](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.aspx) namespace to communicate with AWS's API. This in turn is using the [HttpClientHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.aspx) to create an [HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.aspx). In so doing extra headers like `Host`, `Content-Length` and `Connection` are added to the message.

My question is, how do I go about inspecting the message after I have called [PostAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138242.aspx) and the headers have been added, but before it is sent to the server so I can compute and add the signature?

I could obviously simply just specify these headers myself. But that only helps for known headers. If a different [HttpMessageHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler.aspx) is used (e.g. the [WebRequestHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.webrequesthandler.aspx)) then different headers may be added (for example `Content-Encoding` and `Cache-Control`). If I don't know about all the headers in the message I will not be able to compute the correct signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most, and probably all, AWS services don't actually require you to include *all* The headers.  Amazon apparently anticipated that this would be problematic, for exactly the reason you mention.

> The canonical headers consist of a list of all the HTTP headers *that you are including* that are part of the AWS request. As a minimum you must include host header, and different services might require other headers. [emphasis added]
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html

Typically, the headers you *need* to add are the ones you would already know about at the application level, such as any service-specific `x-amz-*` headers.  Examples of headers you don't need to worry about including would include `User-Agent:`.  One header often added by the http client library is the `Date:` header, but if you include a properly-formatted `x-amz-date:` header with the same date you used to calculate the signature, the actual `Date:` header will be ignored when the signature is validated, and your alternate will be used, instead.

I realize this doesn't directly answer your question, but I suspect what you are anticipating needing to do may be tedious or impractical, so I thought this information worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this has moved me forward, so happy to accept this as the answer.